# Never ending inflation

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

There are a lot of different models of inflation in cosmology, with plenty of different features and issues.

I read that the problem with some models is that they introduce a never-ending inflation, but I can't find an example of it.

Anyway, I thought that indefinite inflation could only happen in a true de-Sitter space, while if we have a quasi-de-Sitter space, it would always be an end at some point. Eventually after a very long stage of inflation, but still - there is an end.

So, am I correct? Is the problem of never ending inflation a tough one? Is it a problem that often arise?